Choosing between infinitive and conjugated form
I am confused whether the following phrase is correct:

We demand the equation have at least one root...

It sounds a bit strange to me, but I have a feeling that the bare infinitive 'have' should be used here, similarly to 'let it BE'. Also I am not sure whether I need 'that' after 'demand'.
What are the correct ways of saying it?

On the other hand we demand that he be suspended is a valid sentence.

Collins dictionary recommends either that or to+INF. "We demand the equation have at least one root" seems equivalent to "We demand that the equation have at least one root" (with a subjunctive "have" to express an order), but I'm not sure if it's legitimate (I looked in some dictionaries but couldn't see anything matching it). Adding "that" would probably be better.

@user405662, it would make sense in a context like an exam question: Give an equation for [blah blah]. We demand that the equation have at least one root in R.  Admittedly, the we demand part is oddly worded for an exam question, but the grammar is correct.

It also might be used if you're setting out the conditions for some procedure to work or something to be true: "If we are to take the square root, we demand that X is positive" (although "require" is probably better). But it would be good if the OP provided more information on how it is being used: is it in a proof, an exam question, or something else?

Now see, @StuartF, I would have said, “we demand that x be positive.”

@StuartF It is being used in the statement of a theorem. This is not the precise example that I have. I have something like "We can relax the conditions on the system and demand it have a unique solution for every $a_n$ and for $a$". Also I agree here with PaulTanenbaum about "be" instead of "is". This is, basically, the source of my question.

This may be syntax ideosyncratic to mathematics.

The word "demand" seems a bit odd to me; usually one would use "require." Is "demand" some sort of specialized mathematical terminology?
